# Symbolic links when formatted

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, format

I have a symbolic link in C drive to a location on D drive. If I delete the C drive partition or format C drive, will it delete/destroy the files on D drive? I run windows 7

Answer (score 3):

**No, it won't**, just like deleting a symlink manually won't affect the originals. The actual files remain completely in the D: drive.

Comment: I asked a related question here: http://superuser.com/questions/670653/registry-and-symbolic-links-when-formatting