# Registry and Symbolic Links When Formatting

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, symbolic-link

I had moved a folder to another drive and then established a symbolic link with mklink (in Windows 7). Now I want to format the original hard drive that I linked to. I understand that the data on the drive I won't be formatting will be safe, but what about the connection to the registry? When Windows formats does it account for this? If not, what is a good way to handle it?

Comment: This is related to http://superuser.com/questions/421919/symbolic-links-when-formatted?rq=1.